# value of $\alpha$ for which the infimum of the set is greater than or equal to $1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y(x)$ be the solution of the differential equation $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-y=0$$ such that $y(0)=2$ and $y'(0)=2\alpha$. Find all the values of $\alpha \in [0,1)$ such that the infimum of the set $$\{y(x)|x \in R\}$$ is greater than or equal to $1$.

By substituting $y=e^{mx}$ and using the initial values we get

$y=(1+\alpha)e^{x}+(1-\alpha)e^{-x}$. Now for the condition to be met we nedd $y \ge 1$. BY
A-M and G-M inequality $$(1+\alpha)e^{x}+(1-\alpha)e^{-x} \ge 2\sqrt{1-\alpha^{2}}\ge 1$$
$$\implies1-\alpha^2\ge\frac{1}{4}\implies 0\le\alpha \le\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

I just want to confirm the answer.

Am I right?